# How to run systemd applications on dotnet version 6.0, if i have 6.0 and 3.1 installed

Tags: linux, .net-core, .net-6.0, systemd

i use OS Centos

> rpm -qa | grep dotnet ..... dotnet-runtime-6.0-6.0.9-1.x86_64
>
> ```
> dotnet --version
> 3.1.110
> ```

And i localinstall runtime 6.0

> ```
> dotnet --info
>  .NET runtimes installed:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> ```

How i can use runtime 6.0 for running systemd applications?

systemd unit error -

> The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it about unit tests or systemd applications?

Comment: It's about applications

Comment: What does this question have to do with C#? Unless the tag is specifically relevant based on the tag description, please remove it.

Comment: Ok, i remove tag

Answer (score 0):

I find answer.

1. Remove 6.0.9 and install 6.0.0 aspnet-runtime
2. env at systemd unit path=/usr/lib64/dotnet/
   Microsoft.NETCore.App dirrectory was containing only version 3.1.11

In my case i change path=/dotnet/shared/
Where dirrectory Microsoft.NETCore.App containing versions 3.1.11 and 6.0.0